# StateError (Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform) on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I'm new to flutter. I have a problem that I can't get over. I'm getting 'StateError (Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform)'.

`class Recipes extends StatelessWidget {

CollectionReference recipes = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(emailadresi);

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
.....
.....
.....
child: StreamBuilder(
stream: recipes.snapshots(),

```
      builder: (context,snapshot){
        final docs = snapshot.data?.docs;
   final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }
         
        return Scrollbar(
        child: ListView.builder(
```

physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
shrinkWrap: true,

```
          itemCount:docs?.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
            return  Container(
                  height: 100,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
            child: Card(
               color: Color.fromARGB(198, 243, 240, 51),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
),
              child:ListTile(
              leading: Image.asset(
    "lib/assets/logo_ust.png",
    height: 40,
    width: 60,
  ),
              title: Text(docs?[index]['Aidiyet']),
              subtitle: Text(docs?[index]['Durum']),
            )));
          },
        )
  );}),
```

`

I could not embed most of the things written on the internet into my code.

Answer (score 0):

**'StateError (Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform)'.**

The error simply indicates that the Document field which you are trying to access doesn't exist.

The error exists at this line of code:

```
title: Text(docs?[index]['Aidiyet']),
          subtitle: Text(docs?[index]['Durum']),
```

Check the Document on firebase firestore that if the given fields **'Aidiyet'** and **'Durum'** exist or not!
Also check if your query **' FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(emailadresi);'** is correct and providing the required output.

Comment: thanks.After adding data without any spaces in the database, the program became stable.